# Blending two images using pilimages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to blend two images using pilimages from inside a function, .6 of image 1 and .4 of image 2. I have looked online everywhere and could not find a help.

Here is what i came up with so far:

```
import pilimages

def blend(pic1, pic2):
    new_img = pilimages.Image(pic1.getWidth(), pic1.getHeight())
for y in range(0, pic1.getHeight()):
    for x in range(0, pic1.getWidth()):

return new_img
```

and here i stop.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PIL Image module - as opposed to pilimages :

PIL documentation [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of looking to find [documentation for pilimages](http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/python/cs12python/imageapi.html) - there's not much to it.

The basic blending operation is pretty simple when you don't have an alpha value to contend with:

```
def blend_pixel(pix1, pix2, part1=0.5):
    part2 = 1.0 - part1
    return tuple(int(p1 * part1 + p2 * part2) for p1,p2 in zip(pix1, pix2))
```

Now just apply it to each pixel:

```
new_img.setPixel(x, y, blend_pixel(pic1.getPixel(x, y), pic2.getPixel(x, y), 0.6))
```